# How to update textboxes in main thread from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

How you update textboxes and labels in the main thread from a new thread running a different class.

MainForm.cs (Main thread)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        Test t = new Test();

        Thread testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.HelloWorld));
        testThread.IsBackground = true;
        testThread.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(string text)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
    }

}

public class Test
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        MainForm.UpdateTextBox("Hello World"); 
        // How do I execute this on the main thread ???
    }
}
```

I have looked at the examples on here but cant seem to get it right. Please could someone give some good links.

I have started again fresh so I don't mess up my code. If anyone would like to put up a working example with my example that would be great.

Also if I had to update multiple objects like textboxes and labels etc (not all at the same time) what would be the best way to go about it, having a method for each textbox or is there a way to do this with one method?

Comment: welcome to SO.  You can edit your question to add additional information, and you can leave comments on answers to a question you have asked (and on anything after you hit 50 rep).

Answer (score 8):

Invoke or BeginInvoke, e.g.

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    MainForm.UpdateTextBox("Hello World"); 
});
```

---

@tiptopjones I guess you're asking also how to get a reference to the form.  You could make your HelloWorld method take an object parameter, use the ParameterizedThreadStart delegate, and then pass a reference to the form as a parameter to the Thread.Start method.  But I would suggest reading about anonymous methods which makes it a lot easier and keeps everything strongly typed.

```
public class MainForm : Form {
    public MainForm() {
        Test t = new Test();

        Thread testThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { t.HelloWorld(this); });
        testThread.IsBackground = true;
        testThread.Start();
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox(string text) {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
        });
    }
}

public class Test {
    public void HelloWorld(MainForm form) {
        form.UpdateTextBox("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

When you get comfortable with that you could read up on lambda expressions and do it like:

```
Thread testThread = new Thread(() => t.HelloWorld(this));
```

Comment: Hey, its preferable to edit your question to add more information rather than provide another answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the [`BeginInvoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), which will queue a delegate to be executed asynchronously on the UI thread.

If you need the background thread to wait until the function finishes on the UI thread, you can call [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) instead.

Note that you will need a reference to the instance of your form; you should probably pass that to the `Test` constructor and store it in a private field.

---

The [BackgroundWorker component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) will do all of this automatically using the `ReportProgress` method; you should consider using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im new to c# and would need an example to work off so I can understand how it works.

Comment: @tiptop: Then you should probably use a BackgroundWorker.  [MSDN has examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc.aspx).

Comment: Any WinForms developer should understand how to update the UI in a threadsafe manner, and both approaches are valid options to understand

Comment: ...also worth warning that the `SynchronizationContext.BeginInvoke()` used to switch to the UI thread is different from `Delegate.BeginInvoke()`, the same for `Invoke() on each Type`.  If you're doing multithreaded WinForms then that ambiguity can mess with you

Answer (score 1):

The prefered way in WinForms is to use the SynchronizationContext

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    SynchronizationContext ctx;

    public MainForm()
    {
        ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Test t = new Test();

        Thread testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.HelloWorld));
        testThread.IsBackground = true;
        testThread.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(string text)
    {
        ctx.Send(delegate(object state)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");

        },null);
    }    
}

public class Test
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        MainForm.UpdateTextBox("Hello World"); 
        // How do I excute this on the main thread ???
    }
}
```