# Prevent the application from exiting when the Console is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I use `AllocConsole()` to open a Console in a winform application.

How can I prevent the application from exiting when the Console is closed?

**EDIT**

The update of completionpercentage from time to time is what I want to show in console

```
    void bkpDBFull_PercentComplete(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", e.Percent);
    }
```

I tried the richtextBox as the alternative

```
       s =(e.Percent.ToString());
       richTextBox1.Clear();
       richTextBox1.AppendText("Percent completed:  " +s +"%");
```

But I can't see the completionpercentage update time to time. It only appears when it is 100% complete.

Any alternative?

Comment: You mean close using `X`button?

Comment: yes the x button on the console

Comment: You cannot stop or disable that.  You can get a notification for it with SetConsoleCtrlHandler() but the ExitProcess() call is always made after that.  Don't use a console if you can't afford that.

Comment: @HansPassant Would it be possible is OP calls `FreeConsole` after handling the console's closing event to separate the WinForm app from the console? Or will ExitProcess be called first?

Comment: Not afterwards, it would have to be done in the callback.  No idea if that could work, somebody ought to try it :)  Odds are not great, you'd expect Windows to increment the reference count on the handle.

Comment: *Looks at OP* :D - I just gave it a go and it didn't seem to work. WinForm closed as well.

Comment: Alternatively you can disable close button will it be helpful for you?

Comment: What would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a task that seldom pops up but I had something similar and decided to go with a couple hacks.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/545f1768-8038-4f7a-9177-060913d6872f/disable-close-button-in-console-application-in-c

-Disable the "Close" button on a custom console application.

You're textbox solution should work as well. It sounds a lot like your calling a function from the main thread that is tying up the form which is also on the main thread and is causing you grief when updating your textbox.  Consider creating a new thread and either an event handler to update your textbox or use the invoke methodinvoker from the new thread to update the textbox.  Link below from an already answered question on how to complete this.

[How to update textboxes in main thread from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446048/how-to-update-textboxes-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)

```
public class MainForm : Form {
    public MainForm() {
        Test t = new Test();

        Thread testThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { t.HelloWorld(this); });
        testThread.IsBackground = true;
        testThread.Start();
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox(string text) {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
        });
    }
}

public class Test {
    public void HelloWorld(MainForm form) {
        form.UpdateTextBox("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959643/why-does-closing-a-console-that-was-started-with-allocconsole-cause-my-whole-app). As mentioned in the answers, there is `no way to stop the application from getting closed.`

But as a workaround, you can have your `own text output solution` described in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can build first the console application that recieves arguments and writes it to the console. Place it, where the main application starts. 
From main application you can first kill process and then reopen it with a new argument.
It's the altarnative way.